# loop through range and insert unique data to access database

Tags: sql, database, loops, ms-access, ado

Hope you're all having a good day.  I'm looping through a range from an open workbook and for each loop i need to check if the details are in my access table and if not insert the details.  I have the following code which i think should work well but seems excel has an issue with opening and closing a RecordSet each loop.   Think that's the issue anyway as it doesn't throw any exception it just stops responding and i have to close the workbook

The loop it's self works great as I've tested without the SQL part and it completed over 100K records in under 1 minute. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

```
With dbConnection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        .ConnectionString = dbConnectionString
        .Open
            ItemsAdded = 0
            dbRecordSet.ActiveConnection = dbConnection
            For i = 1 To DataFile.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                oSQL = _
                "Select * From " & TableName & " Where CompanyName = """ & Trim(DataRange(i, 1)) & """" & _
                " And CommCode = """ & Trim(DataRange(i, 2)) & """;"
                dbRecordSet.Open oSQL, dbConnection

                If dbRecordSet.EOF = True Then 'Does not exist in the access database so add it
                    dbRecordSet.Close
                    dbConnection.Execute "INSERT INTO [" & SearchType & "Table_" & oYear & "] (CompanyName, CommCode, GoodsDescription, MonthsImported, " & _
                    "AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Town_City, County, PostCode) VALUES " & _
                    "(""" & DataRange(i, 1) & """, """ & DataRange(i, 2) & """, """ & Replace(DataRange(i, 3), """", "") & """, """ & DataRange(i, 4) & """, """ & _
                    Replace(DataRange(i, 5), """", "") & """, """ & DataRange(i, 6) & """, """ & DataRange(i, 7) & """, """ & DataRange(i, 8) & """, """ & DataRange(i, 9) & """);"

                    ItemsAdded = ItemsAdded + 1
                Else: dbRecordSet.Close
                End If
            Next i
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: I believe the `dbRecordSet.Close` should be within the `Else:` statement if you want to close it once the insertion query takes place?

Comment: Hi Fishing Code. Thanks for posting. I have the rs closing in the else statement "Else:dbRecordSet. Close" so think that's OK.